# How can space time be bent?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Einstein’s theory of general relativity states that Gravity is not a force per say but it is the bending of the space-time grid making a dent by the object it is holding that creates a gravitational pull! But Space is space, IT’S EMPTY, **how can it possibly behave as a surface made up of grids that bends when it holds a celestial body**?

What I don’t get is how can empty space time with absolutely nothing bent while holding celestial bodies? I am well aware of the trampoline analogy but Trampoline is ‘made up’ of something, i.e. rubber which is made up of atoms and molecules i.e. matter and has this “property” to stretch! Space time is not made up of anything! So how can it be bent and stretched?

Besides doesn’t it contradict the special theory of relativity which states that space-time are FLAT! How can both of them be true at the same time?

Comment: Space isn't nothing. Space is something. I believe the flat thing is in the absence of mass (or averaged over large scales since there is a lot more space than there is mass). Local deformities in that flatness due to the presence of mass is separate from whether space *itself* is flat or curved.

Comment: Also, this appears to be a respost.

Comment: The "special" theory of relativity refers to the special case in which gravity is negligible, i.e. flat spacetime.

Comment: Is the unit sphere curved?  What is it made of?

Answer (score 4):

> But Space is space, IT’S EMPTY.

Ok. But, there is no cause for alarm.

> how can it possibly behave as a surface made up of grids that bends when it holds a celestial body? Besides doesn’t it contradict the special theory of relativity which states that space-time are FLAT!

*General* relativity is different from *special* relativity. You are correct that spacetime is flat in *special* relativity. But this is not true in *general* relativity.

This is the whole point of *general* relativity. Namely, to account for gravity via the introduction of curvature to the metric.

The "metric" can be thought of as a 4x4 matrix that instructs us how to perform the dot product of four-vectors. In *special* relativity the metric is constant and diagonal. In *general* relativity the metric is not, and this is what we mean when we say spacetime is curved.

> How can both of them be true at the same time?

As discussed above, they are not really true "at the same time." *Special* relativity can be thought of as a *special* case of *general* relativity. Though both can be thought of as "true" in their realm of applicability.

This as analogous to how Newtonian dynamics is a special case of relativistic dynamics. They aren't true "at the same time." But Newtonian dynamics is still very useful for most calculations.

As another analogy, consider the surface of the earth. If you walk along a street in your home town, it seems pretty flat. But then someone tells you the earth is round. How can they both be true "at the same time." They are not really applicable to the same situation: One deals with a local perspective and one deals with a global perspective.

Comment: Let’s leave the difference for now. What I don’t get is how can empty space time with absolutely nothing bent while holding celestial bodies? I am well aware of the trampoline analogy but Trampoline is ‘made up’ of something, I.e. rubber which is made up of atoms and molecules, and has this “property” to stretch! Space time is not made up of anything! So how can it be bent and stretched?

Comment: This might help https://youtu.be/wrwgIjBUYVc

Comment: @A.M. There is a theory called Loop Quantum Gravity, and it states that spacetime is made out of tiny loops: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity. I personally don't know the subject but I think it is useful for the time being. Note that this theory still has not has been proven correct. If the wiki to too difficult, I recommend watching some videos online to help visualize the concept. Just search for them, there should be plenty.

Comment: @A.M. I also recommend this video as it explains how gravity "pulls" objects: https://youtu.be/UKxQTvqcpSg. Warning, it might blow your mind...

Comment: @A.M. I find those analogies with bent rubber sheets and trampolines to be very frustrating as well. They are *very* imperfect analogies. The analogies attempt to explain complex mathematical formulas in more familiar terms. There is no good and correct intuitive analogy, because we have no real intuition about substantially curved spacetime. If you really want to know what is going on you need to study a lot of math and physics, unfortunately (or not unfortunately if you like math and physics).

Comment: @hft I totally agree. Understanding the math behind the physics is the key to understanding the concepts. No analogy is perfect and it might even lead you astray from what is really going on. You can only have a "relative understanding" of the concept with analogies, but the math provides "absolute understanding". And this takes many years of hard work to master.

Comment: I don't like the rubber sheet analogy either. I find it more intuitively useful to think of curvature as being a tilting of the direction of the time axis, such that when I look at the curved space from a distance, one tick of my clock is a little less than one tick of your clock plus a little bit of displacement in space.

Answer (score 3):

"Stretch" is just kind of an analogy.   What mass and energy do is change rules of geometry in their vicinity, which govern how points in space and time are connected to each other.  For instance, in normal Cartesian Coordinates, the formula for distance $ds$ between two points very close together is

$ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$

This is simply Pythagorean Theorem.
In special relativity, we need to add time to this to define a "space time distance" and for physical reasons it is the opposite sign to spatial coordinates, so we get:

$ds^2 =  –c^2dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$

This is a "flat" spacetime. Now- going a step further, in general relativity, we have to account for the effect of curvature caused by mass and energy, so the distance between two nearby points becomes:

$ds^2 = g_{00} dt^2 + g_{11} dx^2 + g_{22} dy^2 + g_{33} dz^2 +...$ (and possibly cross terms like $g_{01} dt\ dx$...)

These $g$ coefficients form a 4x4 matrix called the *spacetime metric*, which is the main thing that physicists use Einstein's equations to solve for in a given scenario, given a certain distribution of mass and energy.    The coefficients themselves can be functions of $x, y, z, t$

So in a nutshell, it's not really "bending and stretching," it is altering geometry which forces the trajectories of objects to change, or "bend."

Comment: Nice answer. Is g00 always negative?

Comment: The time coefficient $g_{00}$ has to be the opposite sign as the space ones $g_{ii}$. 
 Except inside a black hole (and maybe other crazy scenarios) where the time one and the radial spatial one flip signs.  This is why nothing can move radially outward, or even remain stationary, inside a black hole. Not because "escape velocity is faster than light" or whatever, but the same reason normally you can't stand still or go backward in time.   There are just, well, no paths available to do that.